# How to get element value after it been added to the page jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to get a value from a list box after it has been added to the page the listbox **ID** is **ql_domain_groups** i need somthing like $('#').live() the only reason why i am not using live is becuase i dont not want to click something to get the value i am trying to get the information into Ajax

```
        function GetQLDomainPages(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/ql_pagefinder.php",
        data:   "domain_id=***Need To Get The Info HERE ***",
        success: function(html){
            $("#select_page_ql").html(html);

    }
    }); 

    }
```

Comment: "Value from a list box..." Do you mean the selected value or all of the values?

Comment: Please understand the implications of building the POST data yourself, it's much better *not* to do this, unlike your original code and the accepted answer below.  Do it right, for whomever has to maintain your code later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "listbox" is a "select" element

```
function GetQLDomainPages(){
    var data = "domain_id=" + $("#ql_domain_group :selected").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/ql_pagefinder.php",
        data: data
        success: function(html){
            $("#select_page_ql").html(html);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: There's no need for the more expensive selector here, just `$("#ql_domain_groups").val()` does the job.  Also, this isn't s afe way to create your POST data, what if the value contained a `&`?

Comment: picky, picky... don't worry, I'm sure you'll get picked as the answer

Comment: it's not a matter of being picky, it's giving code that works *everywhere*, not in certain cases, always promote good coding practices with your answers :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) directly in your `data` object, like this:

```
function GetQLDomainPages(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/ql_pagefinder.php",
    data: { domain_id: $("#ql_domain_groups").val() },
    success: function(html){
      $("#select_page_ql").html(html);
    }
  }); 
}
```

There's no need for event handlers to get a value, you can get it at any time.  In this case we're getting the latest value for submission via AJAX.